# Подсчет количества статей в родительской категории

Tags: mysql

Так вот выглядит таблица категорий, реализована безграничная вложенность

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles_cat_baby` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`realid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`refid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`name` text NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
`kartinka` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Таблица статей

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles_baby` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` text NOT NULL,
`text` longtext NOT NULL,
`moderation` int(1) NOT NULL default '2',
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`prosmotrov` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Подсчет количества статей в категории - mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `articles".$prefixbaby."` WHERE `id_cat`='".$row['id']."';"),0)

Вопрос: как подсчитать количество статей в родительской категории?

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  articles_cat_baby AS c,
  articles_baby AS a
WHERE
  c.id = $id AND
  a.id_cat = c.refid
```

P.S: У вас ужасные имена колонок

Comment: Аналогично.